# Powershell Oracle connection using SecureStore

Tags: oracle, powershell, connection

I need to be able to run a script and get the `Get-Secret` and run `$sqlQuery` on same line

This works:

```
Get-Secret -Vault DBASecretStore -Name dbautil -AsPlainText | sqlplus dbautil/
```

But I need to be able to run `$sqlQuery` too and this doesn't work.  I need to be able to connect then run the `@sqlQuery`

```
    $sqlQuery = @"
        SET LINESIZE 200
        SELECT name 
        FROM v`$database;
"@
$sqlQuery | Get-Secret -Vault DBASecretStore -Name myuser -AsPlainText | sqlplus myuser/  > dbname.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the query to disk and reference the script file in the command:

```
$sqlQuery |Set-Content temp_query.sql
Get-Secret -Vault DBASecretStore -Name dbautil -AsPlainText | sqlplus dbautil/ "@$PWD/temp_query.sql"
Remove-Item temp_query.sql
```